# Why selectedRowKeys in onChange of table antd is not a number array?

Tags: typescript, next.js, antd

I work in a `Nextjs` project with `typescript` and `antd`.

I use a table of `antd` and user can select row.

```
const rowSelection = {
  onChange: (selectedKeys: any[], selectedRows: Mission[]) => {
    console.log(selectedKeys);
  }
}
```

the result: `[12, 11, 10]`

It's a number array.

but if I change into `selectedKeys: number[]`:

```
Type '{ onChange: (selectedKeys: number[], selectedRows: Mission[]) => void; getCheckboxProps: (record: Mission) => { disabled: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type 'TableRowSelection<Mission>'.
  Types of property 'onChange' are incompatible.
    Type '(selectedKeys: number[], selectedRows: Mission[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(selectedRowKeys: Key[], selectedRows: Mission[], info: { type: RowSelectMethod; }) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'selectedKeys' and 'selectedRowKeys' are incompatible.
        Type 'Key[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
          Type 'Key' is not assignable to type 'number'.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
Table.d.ts(22, 5): The expected type comes from property 'rowSelection' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProps<Mission> & { children?: ReactNode; } & { ref?: Ref<HTMLDivElement> | undefined; }'
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [antd documentation](https://ant.design/components/table#rowselection) on `rowSelection`, `onChange` accepts 3 params which are `selectedRowKeys`, `selectedRows` and `info:{ type }`. And if you read again on `selectedRowKeys`, the type is `string[]|number[]`.

Obviously if you typed it as `any[]` then there will be no problem. But if you typed `selectedRowKeys[]` as `number[]`, you may encounter error as `onChange` could be called with values that are not numbers (e.g. an array of strings).

TLDR, try `selectedKeys = string[]|number[]` instead.